# onClick doesn't render new component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code in React and I have no idea why it doesn't work. Basically I want it to add an instance of my component whenever the button is clicked.

```
addList = () => {
    return <List />
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={ this.addList }>Add new list</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your `addList` function isn't rendering anything.  Try setting state in your function and using the state to determine what to render in your render function.

Try this instead:

```js
addList = () => {
  this.setState({
    showList: true,
  });
}

render() {
  const renderedList = this.state.showList === true ? <List /> : null;
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={ this.addList }>Add new list</button>
      {renderedList}
    </div>
  );
}
```